# Specify the INSTALLLOCATION of packages in WiX inside the Burn managed bootstrapper

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I have a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.6 bundle (using [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn)) and managed bootstrapper that install several [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) packages. Some of the packages install to a common location (`C:\program files\MyApp`).

I want to let the user choose the install location inside the managed bootstrapper application ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), especially because the application is large to install; about 1 GB). How can I specify the INSTALLLOCATION for each [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) packages inside my bundle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an [MsiProperty](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msiproperty.html) child for each MsiPackage to specify INSTALLLOCATION=[BurnVariable]. Then use Engine.StringVariables to set BurnVariable.

For example, in your bundle you set:

```
<Bundle ...>
    <Variable Name='BurnVariable' Value='bar' />
    ...
    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage Source='path\to\your.msi'>
            <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[BurnVariable]" />
        </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

See also the [FireGiant](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912207-Pass-Properties-to-MsiPackage-from-Bundle-) explanation on this topic.

Then in the managed bootstrapper you can do something similar to this:

```cs
Engine.StringVariables["BurnVariable"] = "C:\program files\MyApp";
```

Comment: I am trying to read some environment variables from burn and pass it to the MSI's within, but I use the default BA. Can you explain what I need to do? I saw the code in variable.cpp burn -> engine. Is that where I have to add the new variable?