# Custom WiX Burn bootstrapper user interface?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I'm creating an installation package with WiX 3.6 primarily so I can take advantage of the [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bootstrapping features. So far I have several MSI packages bundled together that will be installed with the built-in bootstrapper application (`WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense`).

I have read that Burn allows the default bootstrapper application to be replaced by specifying a custom `UX.dll`, but I haven't yet been able to locate any resources that describes how the custom `ux.dll` is constructed (that is, how it integrates with the Burn engine, what technologies do I use, what interfaces should I implement, etc.).

My goal is to create a branded bootstrapper that can collect arbitrary information from a user and pass that information onto the various bundled MSI files, EXE files, etc.

So I have two questions really:

1. To what degree is the default bootstrapper application customizable?
2. Are there any resources available that describe how to construct a custom `UX.dll`?

Comment: I don't know enough about Burn to answer your question, but I don't think the documentation really exists yet, aside from [this](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm). There is also some explanation from Rob Menshing from a [recent newsgroup thread](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-in-3-6-td6890113.html) about the state of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I did find the Bootstrapper Application Interface documentation in the CHM that is installed with the WIX toolkit.  That's a place to start.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The key thing to know is that there is a **BootstrapperCore.dll** in the WiX binaries that defines a **BootstrapperApplication class** that handles the integration with the Burn engine. I needed to create my own derived class and override the 'Run' method to launch my custom UI.

It was also helpful to use the WixBA project that defines the UI for the WiX bootstrapper as a reference for using the BootstrapperApplication class (src\Setup\WixBA\WixBA.csproj).

The markup I used to reference my custom bootstrapper DLL file is:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.InstallSourceResources)Bootstrapper\FusionInstallUX.dll"/>
  <Payload Id="FusionInstallUX.config"
           SourceFile="$(var.InstallSourceResources)Bootstrapper\FusionInstallUX.BootstrapperCore.config"
           Name="BootstrapperCore.config" Compressed="yes"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

The configuration file consists of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup
            name="wix.bootstrapper"
            type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">

            <section
                name="host"
                type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>

    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <host assemblyName="FusionInstallUX">
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
        </host>
    </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

I also followed other examples and appended

```
[assembly: BootstrapperApplication(typeof([name of class deriving from BootstrapperApplication]))]
```

to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

And lastly, Stack Overflow question [*Specify the INSTALLLOCATION of packages in WiX inside the Burn managed bootstrapper*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588259) describes how to set and use Burn variables to help drive the installation.

Armed with this information I am now prepared to wreak havoc on the world with my very own custom Bootstrapper application!

Answer (score 26):

To supplement @Bill Campbell's answer, I've written a series of blog posts on [writing a custom WiX Bootstrapper in .NET](http://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/) which goes into more depth about the pieces involved, at least for a managed code solution.

Answer (score 6):

Not precisely answer to this question, but if you want to customize appearance of ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost, then [this](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/customizing-burn-prerequisite-boostrapper-image-in-theme-td7205852.html) is what you need to do.

To keep short, you need to declare your variables like this (I put it before BootstrapperApplicationRef)

```
<WixVariable Id="PreqbaThemeXml" Value="tt.thm" />
<WixVariable Id="PreqbaThemeWxl" Value="tt.wxl" />
```

assuming *tt.thm* is your theme file, and *tt.wxl* is your translation file.
Note those files, as well as all files they reference must be included to *BootstrapperApplicationRef* as *Payoload*, like

```
<Payload SourceFile="tt.wxl"/>
<Payload SourceFile="tt.wxl"/>
<Payload SourceFile="cat.png"/>
```

As an example of layout you can use *mbapreq.thm*, found under WiX sources.

Comment: What a great addition to this post! I was able to find _mbapreq.thm_ [here](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources/mbapreq.thm)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other resources listed here, a good bare-bones example of a custom bootstrapper application for Burn is *[Custom WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application](http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/)*.

I found that this is a good place to start with before digging deeper into other more thorough examples like the WixBA project in the WiX sources.

Answer (score 3):

One detail I was missing when setting this up was that I had to include a reference to `WixBalExtension.dll`. That's because the `ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost` is defined in that DLL and used in the bundle like this:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload Name="BootstrapperCore.config"
               SourceFile="MyBA.BootstrapperCore.config" />
      <Payload SourceFile="MyBA.dll"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```