# WiX Burn 3.6 beta - custom UI examples

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

Are there any good references/examples for [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) 3.6 custom UI?

I googled around, but they are broken pieces of the information.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24555877/600559

Answer (score 13):

The WiX installer itself is a good example and the source is freely available via [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) ([WiX 3.6 Beta](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/93929)). Check out the WixUX project, which is the bootstrapper for the WiX 3.6 install. Another Stack Overflow question is *[Custom WIX Burn Bootstrapper user interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840380)*, describing how to get started.

Or if you get the latest [weekly WiX releases](http://wixtoolset.org/releases), the project has been renamed to WixBA. See `src\Setup\WixBA`.

Comment: It never occurred to me to get the source code for Wix itself. Duh!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are scattered all over. I am using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) to maintain my `Product.wxs` with a separate WXS file for the UI. Basically I've downloaded [WiX Edit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) to design the UI.

A good start is to download the WiX source which has WXS UI files you can load into WiX Edit to see how they work. You can download the source from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/releases).

What I did was to copy one of the WixUI files to my project in Visual Studio 2010. When you download the source they can be found under wix36-sources\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib.  In here you will find:

- WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs
- WixUI_InstallDir.wxs
- WixUI_Advanced.wxs
- WixUI_InstallDir.wxs
- WixUI_Minimal.wxs
- WixUI_Mondo.wxs

You can tell from this the dialog flows.  However there are the individual dialog files in here such as:

- CancelDlg.wxs
- BrowseDlg.wxs

You can load these into the Wix Edit to preview the dialog.  You should get a better understanding.

Additionally, the main Wix Page can be found at [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).

I have ordered the Wix book, *[WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](http://www.amazon.co.uk/WiX-Developer-27s-Guide-Windows-Installer/dp/1849513724)*, from Amazon which I hope will help me understand this more.  £30.99 in the UK. Hopefully, this book will be money well spent. There is one review with five stars so fingers crossed.

Comment: It appears that you are answering about creating MSI UI using Wix. lannyboy was asking about customizing Burn UI, the bootstrapper that [typically] disables each bundled MSI's UI.