# Migrate WiX UI to Burn

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a working WiX installer with a custom UI using a WixUI_Mondo_MyApp.wxs file. I have to extend my installer to also run another exe installer. I understand Burn is the way to do this.

I created a Burn project that chains my original MSI with the custom UI (using DisplayInternalUI="yes"), and that works fine. But I don't want two UIs popping up (the Burn default UI, and my MSI UI), and I need to get some info from the MSI UI to determine if I should install the other exe (it will listed as one of the features).

I suppose the proper solution would be to migrate my UI code from my MSI to my Burn project, but I can find no docs on describing how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no migration path; MSI UI is declarative using the MSI UI tables and Burn supports arbitrary code in a bootstrapper application. If you have any logic in your UI customizations, you'd have to write a custom bootstrapper application to get that in a bundle.