# Wix Burn - custom template

Tags: wix

Is there a way to change that redish CD picture in the installer?

[image: Wix bundle app]

Here's the code of the Burn project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="VilmosNagy" UpgradeCode="844c755f-f02b-4dd3-8b9c-af2498f3128c">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\Setup\bin\Release\Setup.msi" />
    </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will want to set the LogoFile. Inside of BootstrapperApplicationRef add

```
<WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LogoFile="path to your logo.bmp"/>
```

More info on [WixStandardBootstrapperApplication](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use a custom theme. Here is an example from https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Rick Bowerman's answer above, you need to use the extended XML schema in order to use WixStandardBootstrapperApplication and remove/replace the icon. Here is a more elaborate example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
...
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="blank.png" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Msi_x86)" />
        <MsiPackage InstallCondition='VersionNT64' SourceFile="$(var.Msi_x64)" />
    </Chain>
...
</Wix>
```

Note that you have to specify something for the LogoFile attribute. It cannot be empty, and leaving the attribute out will restore the horror.