# 'Change' mode of Maintenance Dlg in Wix is disabled

Tags: wix

After the installation of the setup, when the user again launches the setup in Maintenance mode, the 'Change' button appears to be disabled. There is a line below this button saying MyTempService has no independently selectable features.

How do I enable it?

My WixUI_Temp.wxs

```
<Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="ChangeButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyInstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here to see if you can include a default Wix GUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799031/129130 . I can't test this using this machine, but worth a shot.