# How to create own CUSTOM INSTALLER?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I've seen some installer that verifies if the computer has the required resources and installs it automatically if it hasn't.
 EX : Kaspersky antivirus installs .net frameworks itself if its not available in the pc.

How to make such installers.?
I've made a project in vb.net in vs2017. Its desktop application and building an installer now.
Tried msi installer but can't find some modules/libraries/data to learn from.
Any example on that according to my requirement would help me.

InstallShield is paid and have a hefty price tag for me.
What would be a convenient way to make one?

Things I want to do with install shield wizard is :

1. Check for .net frameworks and install them through installer wizard
2. check if the mssql is available
3. If mssql is available then fire some queries(this is an optional thing. Not important)
4. Enters the registry key and all which all other installers do.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time for a proper answer. This will be short. [Quick overview of the major tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) (with links to reviews). **WiX** and **Visual Studio Installer Projects** are free. The latter is not recommended for reasons explained in that link (though it should be able to achieve most of what you want - on paper).

WiX can achieve what you want, as can the commercial tools and they have faster to use features (GUI editors) to help you achieve your goals.

WiX also features [**the Burn bootstrapper / downloader / chainer component**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi) which will allow you to wrap any prerequisite setup in a **setup.exe launcher**. Installshield has **Suite projects** and Advanced Installer has functionality to include prerequisites as explained in the link. All can run SQL queries.