# Wix Burn exepackage property

Tags: properties, wix, exe, burn

I am trying to setup a property to be used within the "InstallCommand" field of "Exepackage", the property is a registry key value which will then be used within the install command to determine the installation location.

I have found the below links with concern of something similar for a msipackage however I am unable to get something similar working for an exepackage?

Can anyone advise please if this is possible?

msipropery reference links:-

[WiX: how to access / change installation directory in managed bootstrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019135/wix-how-to-access-change-installation-directory-in-managed-bootstrapper)

[Specify the INSTALLLOCATION of packages in WiX inside the Burn managed bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588259/specify-the-installlocation-of-packages-in-wix-inside-the-burn-managed-bootstrap?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path. The install location will need to be passed in using `InstallCommand`. Your ExePackage needs to have a command-line option for setting the location.

If your package would be installed from the command line like this

```
setup.exe /install /quiet /InstallLocation=c:\somepath
```

your WiX should look like

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="setup.exe"
            InstallCommand="/install /quiet /InstallLocation=[INSTALLLOCATION]"/>
```

Make sure your Burn Variable is being set in the bundle log.