Wix 5 BootstrapperApplication not prompting for installation directory
I am using a bundle to install my application.  My MSI prompts for an installation directory however when run via the WIX bootstrapper, the prompt for the installation directory does not display. I have tried both of the following:
<BootstrapperApplication>
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="no" LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="..\Resources\cb.bmp" LogoSideFile="..\Resources\sidebar.bmp" Theme="hyperlinkSidebarLicense" />
</BootstrapperApplication>

and
<BootstrapperApplication>
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="..\Resources\cb.bmp" LogoSideFile="..\Resources\sidebar.bmp" Theme="hyperlinkSidebarLicense" />
</BootstrapperApplication>

Does anyone know what I am missing?

The normal way is to use the bootstrapper's UI (SuppressOptionsUI="no") for letting users choose the installation directory. Then pass the InstallFolder variable as a property to the MSI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29142756/7571258

OK I see you have to click options to set the folder.  OK I have that working but unfortunately it is prompting for the directory on an upgrade.  Is there a way to only prompt for the location on a new install?

You could add a RegistrySearch to the Bundle element to detect the previous version and set a variable, then use that variable in the VisibleCondition of the options button: <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" VisibleCondition="NOT WixStdBASuppressOptionsUI AND NOT PreviousVersionDetected">. Here PreviousVersionDetected is the variable you set from the RegistrySearch.

Here is an example to customize a theme. For getting started you can get the built-in theme files from: https://github.com/wixtoolset/Bal.wixext/tree/master/src/wixstdba/Resources

I missed the docs on Wix's website.  This is very simply done using the following code:
<BootstrapperApplication>
    <bal:WixInternalUIBootstrapperApplication LogoFile="..\Resources\LogoFile.bmp" />
</BootstrapperApplication>

