# How can user in Managed Bootstrapper Application select packages to install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, bootstrapper, burn

In my Managed Bootstrapper Application I want to give the user the option to select which packages to install. Therefore I want to set a variable and pass it to the Wix Bootstrapper.
My approach was to do it similar like it is possible with the installfolder ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588259/specify-the-installlocation-of-packages-in-wix-inside-the-burn-managed-bootstrap/7588456)) and check the value with the InstallCondition of the MsiPackage.

```
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage ...
     InstallCondition="[VariableName] = 1"
     ...>
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>

<Variable Name="VariableName" Type="numeric" Value="1"/>
```

Is this the right approach? If yes, has someone an example that works? If no, what is the best way to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our managed bootstrapper we provide the user UI to make a selection of the package they want to install.
Then this information from the model is propagated and handled in the OnPlanPackageBegin and OnPlanPackageComplete.
The package request state can be set to handle this.